# In WSO2 API manager, Is there a way to support hypermedia response (like application/vnd.hal+json or application/vnd.siren+json)?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

In WSO2 API manager, Is there a way to support hypermedia response (like application/vnd.hal+json or application/vnd.siren+json)?

I know concept of [Writing Custom Handlers](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM180/Writing+Custom+Handlers). So I assume I could hypermedia response using this concept. But issue is inside handlers the response is SOAP response(SOAPBody). I use below code snip:

```
RelayUtils.buildMessage(((Axis2MessageContext)messageContext).getAxis2MessageContext());
SOAPBody body = messageContext.getEnvelope().getBody();
```

So it is difficult to convert SOAPBody to different hypermedia response(hal or siren).

Is there a good way to support hypermedia response (like `application/vnd.hal+json` or `application/vnd.siren+json`) in WSO2 API Manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to write a custom message builder/formatter to achieve this. Refer [1, 2 & 3] for more details on how to do this.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Working+with+Message+Builders+and+Formatters

[2] http://charith.wickramaarachchi.org/2010/11/how-to-write-axis2-message-builder.html

[3] https://chamibuddhika.wordpress.com/2011/07/09/writing-a-custom-message-formatter-for-axis2/

Comment: Got the concpt. I will try and let you know. Thanks a lot.